# Create an ArrayList for each item in another ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm writing a servlet that prints all music albums from a database with all their tracknames in html-tables. Because the amount of albums is variable for each artist I'm putting all album objects in an ArrayList:

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Artist artist = (Artist) session.getAttribute("Artist");
    AlbumHelper albumhelper = new AlbumHelper();
    List<Album> albumList = albumhelper.getAllAlbums(artist);

    for(Album album : albumList){
    // a new arraylist for each album    
    }
    request.setAttribute("AlbumList", albumList);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/artist/artistlibrary.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

I'm printing this arraylist with a c:foreach-tag. Now, for each album in the albumlist I need another arraylist containing all the tracks for that album.

All these arraylists should be created and filled before the requestdispatcher does its job.

The names of these arraylists should be dynamically created like: albumName+"Tracks".

Is this the right way to do this? Is it possible to dynamically create arraylists with unique names? I'm still pretty new to JSP and Servlets so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The track data semantically belongs to the `Album` class. Why would you have it outside that class? And for that matter, why is the album list not part of the `Artist` object? It also belongs in there.

Comment: I'm using Hibernate. For every table in the database a class is created.

Comment: Alright then. You could either use a map that maps some unique identifier of an artist to the album list (yuck) or you could write a class that serves as an abstraction of the database layer and actually contains artist information *and* album information. Edit: Same thing for the tracks, obviously.

Comment: Since it's just a school project and the second method sounds a little complicated I'll try it with a map object. Thanks for your help.